# Is it possible to share a big-screen monitor - switching between personal Windows 7 laptops in the office?

Tags: windows-7, display, switching

We use laptops & WiFi in the office. We often make demo to each other and need to show the demo on a big screen monitor hang in the middle of the room :).

I want to switch the display between each of the staffs using LAN wifi network.

Please give me some suggestions on how to do that.

Comment: There are some hardware solutions for this, and maybe even some software options.  Recommend you shop around online.

Answer (score 2):

One person act as master display and controller for the central monitor, and everybody else installs VNC. Master terminal VNC into respective staff's terminal which in turns display on the monitor. During times when this is not used, staff will disable VNC for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You might also look into Synergy - causes another computer's monitor to act as an additional monitor on your system.

There are no wifi-only solutions for this that I'm aware of (like your typical wireless printer) so I believe you'll still need a computer plugged into that monitor, but with synergy and a cheapo netbook, this can still be low-profile.